# Dimension of an algebraic variety defined by two polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

This is a basic question, but the usual definitions of algebraic sets seem quite complicated for a non-specialist.

I wanted to confirm if the following is correct: if we have two nontrivial polynomials $p_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, and if the maximal degree of $p_1$ in the variable $x_1$ is higher than the maximal degree of $p_2$ in the same variable, then $\{(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n)=p_2(x_1,\dots,x_n)=0\}
$ has dimension at most $n-2$.

If yes, how to see this also from the complicated definitions, say in wikipedia? And if no, what further condition should $p_1$ and $p_2$ satisfy for this to be true?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not true if $p_2$ divides $p_1$, eg $x_1^2$ and $x_1$. In any case, what is your definition of dimension?

Comment: And what if $p_2$ does not divide $p_1$ ? would it be the case, for some standard definition of dimension?

Comment: Still no, for example $x_1^2 - 1$ and $x_1$, more generally if $fp_1 + gp_2 = 1$ for some $f$ and $g$. Once you eliminate this class of examples the answer really does depend on the definition of dimension, and a useful answer would depend on the context, which you should [edit] into the question.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is really not a convenient place for these questions since a single polynomial can replace a bunch of separate polynomials: $f_1^2 + f_2^2 + \dots + f_n^2 = 0$ iff $f_1 = f_2 = \dots = f_n = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. You probably mean $x_1^2+1$ in your comment. I have no choice but to work on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Anyway, I understand better now why the concept of dimension is not very straightforward.

Comment: I actually meant $x_1^2 - 1$, since with that $p_1$ and $p_2$ individually have solutions but there are no solutions to $p_1 = p_2 = 0$. If $p_1 = x_1^2 + 1$ then $p_1$ by itself has no solutions, and this is (clearly) related to the sum of squares issue above.